# How to write an efficient GEMM micro-kernel for Zen2 by virtue of avx2 intrinsics?

Tags: c++, performance, matrix-multiplication, hpc, avx

I'd like to be able to write fast kernels that actually make full* (*90% is fine as well) use of my hardware's compute capabilities when expressions are sufficiently compute-intense. As an aside, in a previous question I asked the same for memory-performance instead of compute-performance.

For the matter at hand, I compute C += A*B', where A and B are column major, and A in mxk, B in kxn, and C in mxn. I use small m,n and k=1024, thus all data fits into the L1 cache. And then I run the kernel repetitively. I then tune the kernel with AVX2 intrinsics.

My architecture is Zen2. There are two AVX2 units per core and 16 registers, and the peak performance is 5.9e+1 GigaFlops/second. So I try to use at least 8 independent FMA instructions and use at most 16 avx2 registers. This yields kernel sizes with mxn as 4x8 or 3x12. I also implemented a 4x4 kernel. All kernels and their benchmarked performance are given below.

```
void kernel3x12(double* __restrict__ c, double* __restrict__ a, double* __restrict__ b, size_t L){
    //
    __m256d a0,a1,a2, b0,b1,b2;
    //
    __m256d c00 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c01 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c02 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c10 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c11 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c12 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c20 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c21 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c22 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    //
    for(size_t k=0;k<L;++k){
        //
        a0  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 0]);
        a1  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 1]);
        a2  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 2]);
        //
        b0  = _mm256_loadu_pd(b   );
        b1  = _mm256_loadu_pd(b+4 );
        b2  = _mm256_loadu_pd(b+8 );
        //
        c00 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a0,b0,c00); c01 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a0,b1,c01); c02 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a0,b2,c02);
        c10 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a1,b0,c10); c11 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a1,b1,c11); c12 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a1,b2,c12);
        c20 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a2,b0,c20); c21 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a2,b1,c21); c22 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a2,b2,c22);
        //
        a+=3; b+=12;
        //
    }
    //
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c   ,_mm256_add_pd(c00,_mm256_loadu_pd(c   ))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+4 ,_mm256_add_pd(c01,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+4 ))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+8 ,_mm256_add_pd(c02,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+8 )));
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c+12,_mm256_add_pd(c10,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+12))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+16,_mm256_add_pd(c11,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+16))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+20,_mm256_add_pd(c12,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+20)));
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c+24,_mm256_add_pd(c20,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+24))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+28,_mm256_add_pd(c21,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+28))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+32,_mm256_add_pd(c22,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+32)));
    //
}
// 1.61+1 GigaFlops/second

void kernel_4x8(double* __restrict__ c, double* __restrict__ a, double* __restrict__ b, size_t L){
    //
    __m256d a0,a1,a2,a3, b0,b1;
    //
    __m256d c00 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c01 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c10 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c11 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c20 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c21 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c30 = _mm256_setzero_pd(); __m256d c31 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    //
    for(size_t k=0;k<L;++k){
        //
        a0  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 0]);
        a1  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 1]);
        a2  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 2]);
        a3  = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 3]);
        //
        b0  = _mm256_loadu_pd(b   );
        b1  = _mm256_loadu_pd(b+4 );
        //
        c00 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a0,b0,c00); c01 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a0,b1,c01);
        c10 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a1,b0,c10); c11 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a1,b1,c11);
        c20 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a2,b0,c20); c21 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a2,b1,c21);
        c30 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a3,b0,c20); c31 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a3,b1,c31);
        //
        a+=4; b+=8;
        //
    }
    //
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c   ,_mm256_add_pd(c00,_mm256_loadu_pd(c   ))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+4 ,_mm256_add_pd(c01,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+4 )));
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c+8 ,_mm256_add_pd(c10,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+8 ))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+12,_mm256_add_pd(c11,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+12)));
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c+16,_mm256_add_pd(c20,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+16))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+20,_mm256_add_pd(c21,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+20)));
    _mm256_storeu_pd(c+24,_mm256_add_pd(c20,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+24))); _mm256_storeu_pd(c+28,_mm256_add_pd(c21,_mm256_loadu_pd(c+28)));
    //
}
// 1.72e+1 GigaFlops/second

void kernel(double* __restrict__ c, double* __restrict__ a, double* __restrict__ b, size_t L){
    //
    __m256d b0, a0,a1,a2,a3;
    //
    __m256d c0 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c1 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c2 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    __m256d c3 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    //
    for(size_t k=0;k<L;++k){
        //
        b0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(b   );
        //
        a0 = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 0]); 
        a1 = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 1]); 
        a2 = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 2]); 
        a3 = _mm256_set1_pd(a[ 3]); 
        //
        c0        = _mm256_fmadd_pd( a0 , b0 , c0 );
        c1        = _mm256_fmadd_pd( a1 , b0 , c1 );
        c2        = _mm256_fmadd_pd( a2 , b0 , c2 );
        c3        = _mm256_fmadd_pd( a3 , b0 , c3 );
        //
        a+=4; b+=4;
        //
    }
    //
    _mm256_storeu_pd( c    , _mm256_add_pd( c0 , _mm256_loadu_pd(c   ) ) );
    _mm256_storeu_pd( c+ 4 , _mm256_add_pd( c1 , _mm256_loadu_pd(c+ 4) ) );
    _mm256_storeu_pd( c+ 8 , _mm256_add_pd( c2 , _mm256_loadu_pd(c+ 8) ) );
    _mm256_storeu_pd( c+12 , _mm256_add_pd( c3 , _mm256_loadu_pd(c+12) ) );
    //
}
// 2.27e+1 GigaFlops/second
```

The compile command is

```
g++ -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o -O3 -mavx -ffast-math -march=native -fno-trapping-math
```

My question is: What do I have to change in order to get at least 90% peak performance?

### Complete Code for your convenience

```
/*
g++ -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o -O3 -mavx -ffast-math -march=native -fno-trapping-math
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -o main.exe main.o kernel.o
./main.exe

*/

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
#include<random>
#include<chrono>
#include"kernel.hpp"

#define dim_m 4
#define dim_n 4

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::setw;

struct rng{
    std::random_device          rd;
    std::mt19937                mt;
    std::normal_distribution<>  dist;
    rng(): rd(), mt(rd()), dist(0.0,1.0) {}
    double get(){ return dist(mt); }
};

void set_random(double* x, size_t n, rng& o){
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i){
        x[i] = o.get();
    }
}

void print(double* c, size_t L){
    for(int i=0;i<dim_m;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<dim_n;++j){
            std::cout << std::setw(20) << c[i*dim_n+j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void kernel_ref(double* c, double* a, double* b, size_t L){
    for(size_t k=0;k<L;++k){
        for(size_t i=0;i<dim_m;++i){
            for(size_t j=0;j<dim_n;++j){
                c[i*dim_n+j] += a[k*dim_m+i] * b[k*dim_n+j];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    
    rng o;
    
    int L = 512;
    int J = 100000;
    
    double *a, *b, *c;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t0,t1;
    
    // size_of(double)=8
    // aligned allocation
    /*
    a = std::aligned_alloc(L*4*sizeof(double),4*sizeof(double)); // alignment size, vector size in bytes must
    b = std::aligned_alloc(L*4*sizeof(double),4*sizeof(double));
    c = std::aligned_alloc(4*4*sizeof(double),4*sizeof(double));   // look-up for g++
    */
    a = new double[L*dim_m];
    b = new double[L*dim_n];
    c = new double[dim_m*dim_n];
    set_random(a,dim_m*L    ,o);
    set_random(b,L    *dim_n,o);
    set_random(c,dim_m*dim_n,o);
    
    int branch = 3;
    
    if(branch==1){
        kernel_ref(c,a,b,L);
    }
    if(branch==2){
        kernel(c,a,b,L);
    }
    if(branch==3){
        t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int j=0;j<J;++j){
            kernel(c,a,b,L);
        }
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    
    print(c,L);
    
    double flops = 2.0 * dim_m*dim_n * L * J;
    double time  = std::chrono::duration<double>(t1-t0).count();
    double perf  = flops / time;
    
    /*
    std::free(a);
    std::free(b);
    std::free(c);
    */
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
    
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n" << std::right << std::scientific;
    cout << std::left << "measures:\n";
    cout << std::left << "\t" << setw(20) << "flops"    << " : " << std::right << flops  << "\n";
    cout << std::left << "\t" << setw(20) << "time"     << " : " << std::right << time   << "\n";
    cout << std::left << "\t" << setw(20) << "perf"     << " : " << std::right << perf    * 1.0e-09 << " [GigaFlops/s] ~ "<<     16.0*3.7e+9 * 1.0e-09<<"\n"; // https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Floating_Point_Unit 
    cout << std::left << "\t" << setw(20) << "perf x32" << " : " << std::right << 32*perf * 1.0e-12 << " [TeraFlops/s] ~ "<<32.0*16.0*3.7e+9 * 1.0e-12<<"\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

and then with a header-file for the kernel.cpp .

The results are in Windows 10 with the following MinGW compiler.

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-8.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5' --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-isl=/mingw --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls --disable-build-format-warnings
Thread model: win32
gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5)
```

PS: The question is not targeted to the purpose of acquiring a fast GEMM Micro Kernel, but instead to learn how at all code can be written so as to make full use of available compute resources. Restricting the FLOPS kernel to within the L1-Cache is for simplification.

Comment: Would that even compile with `-mavx`?  GCC should reject `_mm_fmadd_pd` unless you also use `-mfma`, which is implied by `-march=znver2` which is what you should use if tuning for it.  BTW, a carefully cache-blocked matmul can nearly saturate FMA throughput, even if the overall size is too large for L1d.  With N^3 work over N^2 data, there's enough reuse to make it possible.  Of course, having all inputs/outputs hot in L1d is easier!

Comment: It did compile, and the performance results are actual. I post the entire code for your convenience.

Comment: Oh, there's also a `-march=native` in there.  Apparently I wasn't awake enough to notice that.  It makes `-mavx` pointless.  (And `-mavx` alone isn't sufficient.  https://godbolt.org/z/r6nb7WdMK)

Comment: Since the positing of the question, I have tried other kernel sizes non-stop, searched the internet for counselling, and looked out for business contacts to people like @PeterCordes. Whoever is interested in counselling/tutoring, please contact me via kaisong15@proton.me